# Horizontal alignment of a div element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontal align the `div` element with `.slider` class but applying `margin: 0 auto;` is not working. Also please, how to make the slider image responsive?

```css
/* CSS Document */

.header {
  background-image: URL("images/header_top.png");
  height: 80px;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  background-image: URL("images/header_logo.png");
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 84px;
  width: 264px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-image: URL("images/bg_blueprint.jpg");
  width: 100%;
}
.container-main {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider {
  background-image: URL("images/slider_photo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  height: 482px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-main">

    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1 header">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is the slider div is taking max width of its container. In order for a div to align center within a container using `margin:0 auto;`. it itself should have a limited width and height that is smaller than it's container. So to make it center. Change the `max-width:100%` in the `.slider` class to have a width in pixels like `max-width:350px;`

Now to make the image responsive just add the `background-size:contain;` in the `.slider` class.

Here is the .slider class that will work as you want:

```
.slider{
 background-image: URL("http://placehold.it/350x150");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
 height: 482px;
 max-width: 350px;
}
```